# Can't build opentelemetry-collector-contribution image

Tags: docker, open-telemetry, open-telemetry-collector

I want to build my own image of the opentelemetry-collector-contrib.

I have cloned the repo from https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib, and also downloaded one of the previous releases, while standing in the directory
`~/git/opentelemetry-collector-contrib/cmd/otelcontribcol`
where the Dockerfile is located i tried building the image,
`docker build -t opentelemetry-collector .`

This is the output from that command

```
[+] Building 2.9s (9/9) FINISHED
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                   0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 417B                                                                                                                   0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                      0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                        0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/alpine:latest                                                                                       2.9s
 => [prep 1/3] FROM docker.io/library/alpine:latest@sha256:82d1e9d7ed48a7523bdebc18cf6290bdb97b82302a8a9c27d4fe885949ea94d1                            0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                                      0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                        0.0s
 => CACHED [prep 2/3] RUN apk --update add ca-certificates                                                                                             0.0s
 => CACHED [prep 3/3] RUN mkdir -p /tmp                                                                                                                0.0s
 => CACHED [stage-1 1/2] COPY --from=prep /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt                                        0.0s
 => ERROR [stage-1 2/2] COPY otelcontribcol /                                                                                                          0.0s
------
 > [stage-1 2/2] COPY otelcontribcol /:
------
Dockerfile:12
--------------------
  10 |
  11 |     COPY --from=prep /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  12 | >>> COPY otelcontribcol /
  13 |     EXPOSE 4317 55680 55679
  14 |     ENTRYPOINT ["/otelcontribcol"]
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: failed to compute cache key: failed to calculate checksum of ref 9e3fdc3d-3503-4919-a002-afc797437afc::nx8dhy0uobndfpju0yea5tb8d: "/otelcontribcol": not found
```

Comment: Have you considered opening an issue in the collector repository about this?

Comment: You need to build that `otelcontribcol ` first. Check Makefile.

Comment: @JanGaraj Yes ty, I've solved it, while standing in the root directory `make docker-otelcontribcol`